# How get object's from generic List to jsp page with jstl tag <c:foreach>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have generic list with object's:

`List<Enee> ListEnee = new ArrayList<Enee>();
.
.
.`

```
ListEnee.add(new Enee(rs.getString(6),rs.getString(2),rs.getInt(3)))
```

It was formed correct, from SQL with the help of XML.

If needed my class Enee:

```
public class Enee {
private String string1;
private int int3;
private String string2;
public Enee(String string1,String string2,int int3) {
    super();
    this.string1 = string1;
    this.string2 = string2;
    this.int3 = int3;
}
public int getInt3() {
    return int3;
}
public String getString1() {
    return string1;
}   
public String getString2() {
    return string2;
}
public String toString() {
    return string1+string2+int3;
}
```

}

Across my controller:

`request.setAttribute("listenee", sessionBean.getListEnee());`

I through it to my jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="rows" items="${listenee}">
    <td><c:out value="${rows}"/></td>
</c:forEach>
```

it work's, but I need pull out each object individually from generic list.

For example

```
<c:forEach var="rows" items="${listenee}">
    <td><c:out value="${rows.string1}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${rows.string2}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${rows.int3}"/></td>
</c:forEach>
```

I have this, Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to find a value for "string1" in object of class "class_of_generic" using operator "."

Thank you!

Comment: try to post Enee class

Comment: where is string1, string2, int3?

Comment: Did you edit the code/error afterwards without testing? The part "class_of_generic" in the error message is unexpected. Please copypaste code and error unmodified to avoid red herrings and unnecessary forth-back questions. The error in turn is pretty clear: you don't have a public getter method for `string1` on the class as identified by `class_of_generic` (which in turn is a very bad Java naming convention and doesn't match your own `Enee` class, hence the confusion). JSTL/EL in turn has no problems with generics, EL already existed before Java 1.5, so that can't be the cause.

Comment: [7/4/16 11:16:28:328 EEST] 00000031 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: /_PPUZ_NDI_MNS_ENEE/jsp/html/Main.jsp. Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to find a value for "string1" in object of class "ppuz.ndi.ppuz_ndi_mns_enee.db2.Enee" using operator "."

Comment: The error literally says you don't have a `public String getDergh() { return dergh; }` method in `ppuz.ndi.ppuz_ndi_mns_enee.db2.Enee` class.

Comment: I edit my previous comment

Comment: Well, the code in your question is correct. But if you keep editing code for posting here without testing it, then this still doesn't tell that the real code is correct. The exception clearly says real code isn't correct.

Comment: This is a real code with modified variables. And it works correctly. But I can not pull out the object and put in a separate cell.

Comment: Then you're not running the code you think you're running. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart, verify WAR, etc.

Comment: I verify WAR every time when I something changes in my code, when I try to run only <c:forEach var="rows" items="${listenee}">
    <td><c:out value="${rows}"/></td>
</c:forEach> , output is correctly,with current element's,as I expected. But I need get object from generic list in each cell separately.

Comment: Cause of your problem is not visible in the information provided so far. That's all I can tell now. Imagine anyone else in the world trying to reproduce your problem based on solely the information provided so far. It'll work just fine for them on a scratchpad project with everything set to bare defaults and most recent versions and model stubbed with sane values. For hints how to naildown the real cause, see all previous comments.